Example of reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive but not complete relation
Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty set and $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ its power set. The relation $R$ on $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ defined by the subsetrelation for sets, i.e.
$$
(A, B)\in R\quad\text{if, and only if,}\quad A\subseteq B
$$
is reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive, hence a partial order. It is not complete in general and not symmetric.
I do not understand why the relation $R$ is not complete in general. I would say it is. The definition says: a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is complete if for all $a, b\in A$ either $(a, b)\in R$, or $(b, a)\in R$, or both. Could you help me?
Thank you

Hint : Consider the set ${1,2,3}$. Are the subsets ${1,2}$ and ${2,3}$ related in any way?
